# Having issues loading jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery and js in general, so don't judge ;)
So, I saved the script on the server, but for some reason its not loading,you can look at the code by going to the site where I am testing @ http://smit1.byethost7.com/Test/form/form4.html
If you can tell me what I am doing wrong then that be great, thanks!

```
<html>
    <head>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://smit1.byethost7.com/Test/form/form.js"></script>
```

```
    <body>
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="whereEntry" method='post' action=''>
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" class="income_count span1 register_input" id="income" name="income" placeholder="% of income"><br>
                <input type="text" class="income_count span1 register_input" id="income_2" name="income_2" placeholder="% of income"><br>
                <input type="text" class="income_count span1 register_input" id="income_3" name="income_3" placeholder="% of income"><br>
                <input type="text" class="income_count span1 register_input" id="income_4" name="income_4" placeholder="1 of income"><br>
                <input type="text" class="income_count span1 register_input" id="income_5" name="income_5" placeholder="% of income"><br>
                <input type="text" class="income_count span1 register_input" id="income_6" name="income_6" placeholder="% of income"><br><br><br>

                <input type="text" class="span2 register_input" id="income_sum" name="income_sum" placeholder="% of income"><br>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code has not included jquery.js...? Also, please include your code within the question. I have edited your question for you.

Comment: For one thing, you don't include jQuery anywhere in that HTML page. So that may be part of your problem.

Comment: @rory thanks for adding that in for me. I have added -type="text/javascript"- to load the java script but when I still input the number its sum is not showing up in the bottom field where it is supposed to, any suggestions? And thank you all for suggesting the edits!

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually load jQuery in your HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH_TO_JQUERY"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `jquery.js` in your code. Try this, including the file from Google CDN:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://smit1.byethost7.com/Test/form/form.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Included that in the head,I still didn't see any results. Testing tge form @ http://smit1.byethost7.com/Test/form/test3.html

Comment: Check the console for other errors in your code. Not including jQuery at all is the biggest issue though.